# rsa keys verification

Tags: encryption, rsa

So I'm developing my messanging app with encryption evolved using RSA. Currently I came up with this algorithm:

= Update for auth =

[image: img]

**Screenshot:**
[image: img]

In this case private keys are generated only from password, and server knows only password hash just to authorize users (unhashed password is never transmitted to server), therefore is unable to generate private keys or decrypt any old message. If server will fake a public key recipent will be unable to verify signature encrypted with sender's private key.

The problem is that server can fake a sender's private, public key and password when he signs up on a service or requests a password change and recipent will be unable to detect it. So, how can I verify that keys were not faked by the server?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **cryptography** and **crypto protocol design** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JamesKPolk ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So, how can I verify that keys were not faked by the server?

You cannot. So long as the clients only communicate with the server, there's no way for them to distinguish between a "real" remote user and one that's being MITMed or otherwise faked by the server.

I see a couple other serious potential issues here:

- Sending an unsalted hash of a password over the wire (during the login process) is hardly better than sending the password in the clear. An attacker can sniff the hash off the wire to log in -- they don't need the actual password! -- and a non-iterated SHA256 is highly vulnerable to brute force attacks.
- "private key from pass" (also in the login process) implies that you're using some sort of KDF to generate a private key from the user's password. This has multiple negative implications:

  1. Users are generally pretty bad at choosing passwords. This implies that the private keys will also be weak.
  2. If two users happen to use the same password, they will end up with the same private key.
  3. Any user can attack the password (and hence the private key) of any other user that they've communicated with by running the KDF on candidate passwords.
- There is no process specified for negotiating a symmetric encryption key. Using RSA to encrypt messages directly limits each message to the size of the key, and makes it vulnerable to numerous attacks if the data being encrypted is not both random and unique.
- In the message exchange, the user sends the server two copies of every message -- one encrypted to the target user's private key, one encrypted to their own private key. In some situations, this may make it possible to recover the message.

Comment: I do not send hashed or unhashed password over the wire. I send only public key generated from private key generated from password.

Comment: If user choosed bad password - it's there fault. About the "private key duplication" I can go with generating private key from username and password.

Comment: Oh, and also, all this communication goes through SSL. My algorithm is used only to store messages.

Comment: I see `sha256(password)` on the second line of "Auth". And if you don't have that, any user can log in and start sending messages as another user by sending another user's public key.

Comment: Sorry, I took an old image. Going to update it. [Done]

Comment: About sending message encrypted with User #1 and User #2 public key.... User encrypts messages with his own public key for getting message history later. So, if it's only for this user and user knows the password I can go with storing message for message history encrypted with AES.